# Typescript UnpackArrayType for inferred never[] and any[] works incorrectly

Tags: typescript, extends, inferred-type

I was trying to use `(infer R)[]` for `never` and `any` types to unpack arrays.

```
type UnpackArrayType<T> = [T] extends [(infer R)[]] ? R : false;
```

But the result was unexpectable: Typescript neither cast false from "else" (non-array condition) nor detect inferred type R.

[demo link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdmAhgYwNYEEBOnEgCrgQA8eAfFALxQDaeAulBAB7ARwAmAzjQBQCWcAGYRMUAEoBKanQYB%20cVABcUQYgA2nCAG4oAel0r1mqKEhQArpvZRE3OAHs4AWkTZcTgLavUIgFCnoGHQScip4JDQsHHxCEJ19KAArS2AbNT5bX39CKAJIPAhOYAEAc0ooAG9fKBqoACI4CAA3ETrlIKJGlsxSABpamoTzOFQHAHc4GqcoAWR7bAhkYGrahuaRaTbYYK6Nuj69A13RabmFpayBusQ4EC2Om5ADgYGhkfHJqGnZ%20cxF5auj027WCQP2-VeBkeXygZz%20FxWNTqw1G9gm92CKI%20BwSqg00FOv3%20iPqWLRcGB2yIZIm0hxBhpk0J52WJIa5jUagxnQ5ameL1xRgJsKJFyucF5lI6Es5dIhhygMrUMLhxLZw3YEEEAgg7G5Gq1OvY9MM%20JVooBqwN2sa7ClmI4httcoV1qN5pZl1WEo8ACNWiCeX6RPzBWbmfDLUiff7MPag7GXQkYyIPZHfABfXxAA)

```
type UnpackArrayType<T> = [T] extends [(infer R)[]] ? R : false; // false type used as non-array-marker
type UA<T> = UnpackArrayType<T>; // just alias

type TypeTesting = {
    "never": UA<never>,     // unknown  - incorrect
    "never[]": UA<never[]>, // never - correct

    "any": UA<any>,         // unknown  - incorrect
    "any[]": UA<any[]>,     // any - correct

    "unknown": UA<unknown>, // false - correct
    "unknown[]": UA<unknown[]>, // unknown - correct

    "null": UA<null>,       // false - correct
    "null[]": UA<null[]>,   // null - correct

    "undefined": UA<undefined>, // false - correct
    "undefined[]": UA<undefined[]>, // undefined - correct

    "number": UA<number>,   // false - correct
    "number[]": UA<number[]>, // number - correct
}
```

Why `any` and `never` types unpacking as `unknown`?

Comment: both `any` and `never` are sub types of any other type, that is why they are assignable to any other value. So asking the question `never extends X` will always return true regardless of what `X` is.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir looking forward for your answer with more explanation and examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extends` tests relationships between types and then attempts to extract the inferred location.

`any` and `never` both have the property that they are subtypes of any other type (`any` is even stranger as it is also a base type of any other type). So asking the question `never extends T` or `any extends T` will return true for any type `T`.

After the extends question is answered then can we consider the inference question and since there is no good way to extract `R` in `[(infer R)[]]` from `any` or `never` you end up with `unknown`.

You could special case these two universal types subtype:

```
type UnpackArrayType<T> = 
    [T] extends [never]  ? false: // nothing extends never except never itslef
    [T & 1] extends [T & 2]? false : // T & 1 extends T & 2 will only be true if T is any and the & 1 and & 2 get absorbed into any
    [T] extends [(infer R)[]] ? R : false; // false type used as non-array-marker
type UA<T> = UnpackArrayType<T>; // just alias

type TypeTesting = {
    "never": UA<never>,     // false  - correct
    "never[]": UA<never[]>, // never - correct

    "any": UA<any>,         // false  - correct
    "any[]": UA<any[]>,     // any - correct

    "unknown": UA<unknown>, // false - correct
    "unknown[]": UA<unknown[]>, // unknown - correct

    "null": UA<null>,       // false - correct
    "null[]": UA<null[]>,   // null - correct

    "undefined": UA<undefined>, // false - correct
    "undefined[]": UA<undefined[]>, // undefined - correct

    "number": UA<number>,   // false - correct
    "number[]": UA<number[]>, // number - correct
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdmAhgYwNYEEBOnEgCrgQA8eAfFALxQBQUdUA2ngLpQQAewEcAJgM6M4EAG4RMrKAH4oAM0QAbPhABcUAPRqocAPbAAFgEs4Aczadu-LSLFnkEMMCujMUA8D7yIM2vSZQAZFAAjKwcXLwCfoEATMzScorQqhpQeAHBZuGWaTFQAO4G8vJQ2nDyIFAARtDAmACu0AYyqa4CiHAV7TxQ+tCBQVBd6dFQxhCOiJV82pjV3UbA2oMdPnRMoeYRjAAURjI2AEoAlAzMrNIHUKoJSgDc6po3NYRQdUrdiAI6cAC0iNi4H4AW3+qDE1FAkFg6BI5Co8CQaCwOHwhFh9xSACs3hN5AZPtQIS8CJA8BA+MAjKYqABvVZQABEQmcDNUMBhzLEpAANPQ6CknnQflBkDNMBBkMB6UzrJhTqzoUROXLmDyHk4bMLRdgJVLpe0QAr2UQDWq+XyBQolEKRWLdfqOvK2TCDaczfQUgaoFq7ZLCXyGXU4KgdHk4EaYUGQ9ow2rLYlvbadX6A1HQ3AnYq0zGM6reSls2HE9rxX7pXA6kUI0rK-J3RbHlboD7k1KAxWipnjR35G7efzND3i769aneF4jBAeNWgzwJ0IeHHGwmW6W2-RA+OZJOeF3I1ud331bP51Ph63-RuK0Dqphq9fb+749bV-b23Ub2I9zXPyql1oP1vc812oABfaggA)

Note: To extract the element type from a type known to be an array you can also use `T[number]`